# Limit to the recursion depth in tail recursion in languages implementing TCO?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

What is the theoretical/practical limit to the recursion depth in languages implementing Tail Call optimisation? (Please assume that the recurring function is properly tail call-ed).

My guess is that the theoretical limit is NONE, as there is no recursive process, even though it is recursive procedure. Practical limit would be that allowed by the main memory available to be used. Please clarify or correct if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a tail recursive function is optimized, it'll essentially become an iterative function. The compiler reuses the stack frame of the original call for subsequent calls, so you won't run out of stack space. **If you are not allocating any heap memory (or any other kind of memory that's not on the stack, for that matter)**, you can have infinitely deep (as long as you are patient enough ;)) recursion (think of it as an infinite loop; it has the same characteristics).

To summarize, there's no practical limit.

Comment: I am currently waiting for (waiting for (factorial 10000000000) to finish :)

Comment: @Amit are you still waiting? or did you give up. I imagine that would take some time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Mehrdad Afshari wrote, I just want to point out that it is actually very important that tail recursion (or more generally a chain of tail calls) can be potentially infinite, because otherwise you couldn't write a web server, an operating system, an interpreter, a REPL, or really any kind of event processing loop in a functional language.

After all, an operating system is nothing but an infinite loop, and the way to write a loop in a functional language is using tail recursion. If tail recursion weren't infinite, the loop wouldn't be infinite. Therefore, you could not only not write an operating system, the language wouldn't even be Turing-complete.

Basically, this is how you write a web server in a functional language:

```
def loop(queue) = {
  // handle first request in queue
  loop(queue)
}
```

Without infinite tail recursion, this would quickly run out of memory.

Comment: +1 Although most people don't write their own webservers in Scheme, TCO is a crucial part of the usability of such a language in which iteration is either difficult or impossible.